# SQL Server 2008 - Merge Script not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, merge-statement

This merge script i'm writing isn't compiling and I believe I have the correct syntax.

```
MERGE into MyTable ct_current
USING (SELECT '0%' as Description, '0' as ShareAmount) ct_value
    ON ct_current.ShareAmount = ct_value.ShareAmount
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET ct_current.Description = '0%'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (Description, ShareAmount)
    VALUES (ct_value.Description, ct_value.ShareAmount);
GO
```

Error:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'into'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'ct_value'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I had the SQL Server 2008 R2 client, but the server is SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
MERGE MyTable AS ct_current
USING (SELECT '0%' as Description, '0' as ShareAmount) ct_value
  ON ct_current.ShareAmount = ct_value.ShareAmount
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET ct_current.Description = '0%'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (Description, ShareAmount)
  VALUES (ct_value.Description, ct_value.ShareAmount);
```